# Is there an update/refresh method in Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm noob to Swing. I want to have a moving object on a JPanel from point to point. Is there a method which is being called repeatedly so I can stick there coordinate increase?

Comment: I know you are asking for `component.repaint()` and `component.repaint(x, y, width, height)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though one exists: `repaint()`,  it will almost never be used if your code is written  correctly. Just obey the Swing threading rules and you should be OK. Here is a good article about it:

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2007/12/06/unwritten-rule-of-working-with-swings-edt.html

Comment: `it will almost never be used`: reflect some light on my head, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: What I mean is that there are very few cases when it is really needed (like dealing with some weird custom painting). The use case described in the question will work without it.

Comment: The use case will actually need `repaint()` more obviously. :)

Comment: `revalidate()` maybe but not `repaint()` IMO

Comment: Its ok, i know we are having a misunderstanding. But if we just pay a little attention with the OP's tag `graphics` then his meaning of `Object` is more clearer, seemingly he is not mentioning about Component but drawing objects :)

Comment: You may be correct if animation is what the he means. In this case I would use animation library like Trident

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42534/discussion-between-sage-and-eugener)